# Uncaught TypeError while using googleapis library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-api, gmail, vite

I'm getting this error in my Vite + React + TypeScript project (it's located in one of the googleapis library files):

[Uncaught TypeError: class heritage http.Agent is not an object or null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWQwd.png)

It started right when I installed the googleapis library. I wanted to use it so I could send emails but now my page won't even render because of it. Obviously the error doesn't happen when I uninstall said library.

The version I'm using is this one.

[googleapis version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX9g0.png)

I'd appreciate anyone's help!

I don't have a lot of experience, so I really have no idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code